# req.file == undefined, always undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, excel, express, multer

I want to upload the excel file on the MySQL database and then import it back,
I have uses the technologies :
express
multer
mysql2
read-excel-file
sequelize

But when I upload the excel, `req.file` is showing undefined. in the excel controller folder.

I have checked the multer twice but it seems to be right.

I don't know what is the problem ...

Your answer will help me.

Thanks

Server-side code:

```
const multer = require("multer");

const excelFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  if (
    file.mimetype.includes("excel") ||
    file.mimetype.includes("spreadsheetml")
  ) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb("Please upload only excel file.", false);
  }
  console.log("done");
};

var storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: (req, file, cb) => {
    cb(null, __basedir + "/uploads");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    console.log(file.originalname);
    cb(null, `${Date.now()}-bestfile-${file.originalname}`);
  },
});

var uploadFile = multer({ storage: storage, fileFilter: excelFilter });
module.exports = uploadFile;
```

Excel controller

```
const db = require("../../models");
const Branch = db.bestdata;

const readXlsxFile = require("read-excel-file/node");

const upload = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log(req);
    if (req.file == undefined) {
      return res.status(400).send({ msg: "No, Excel File Uploaded" });
    }

    let path = __basedir + "/uploads/" + req.file.filename;

    readXlsxFile(path).then((rows) => {
      // skip header
      rows.shift();

      let branchArray = [];

      rows.forEach((row) => {
        let branchtoArray = {
          id: row[0],
          branch_name: row[1],
          mgr_id: row[2],
          mgr_start_date: row[3],
        };

        branchArray.push(branchtoArray);
      });

      Branch.bulkCreate(branchArray)
        .then(() => {
          res.status(200).send({
            message: "Uploaded the file successfully: " + req.file.originalname,
          });
        })
        .catch((error) => {
          res.status(500).send({
            message: "Fail to import data into database!",
            error: error.message,
          });
        });
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      message: "Could not upload the file: " + req.file.originalname,
    });
  }
};

const GetImport = (req, res) => {
  Branch.findAll()
    .then((data) => {
      res.send(data);
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      res.status(500).send({
        message:
          err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving tutorials.",
      });
    });
};

module.exports = {
  upload,
  GetImport,
};
```

Router:

```
const express = require("express");
const router = express.Router();
const excelController = require("../controller/BestData/excel.controller.js");
const uploadFile = require("../middlewares/upload.js");

let routes = (app) => {
  router.post("/upload", uploadFile.single("file"), excelController.upload);
  router.get("/import", excelController.GetImport);
  app.use("/excel", router);
};

module.exports = routes;
```

Snapshot of postman test

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhsWU.png)

Excel File uploading

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iYDzS.png)

Answer (score 0):

The answer is simple: Destination and path should be the same.:

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).